# What's the correct JsonPath expression to search a JSON root object using Newtonsoft.Json.NET?

Tags: json, filter, json.net, expression, jsonpath

Most examples deal with the [book store example from Stefan Gössner](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e3), however I'm struggling to define the correct JsonPath expression for a simple object (no array):

```
{ "Id": 1, "Name": "Test" }
```

To check if this json contains `Id = 1`.

I tried the following expression: `$..?[(@.Id == 1])`, but this does find any matches using Json.NET?

Also tried [Manatee.Json](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Json) for parsing, and there it seems the jsonpath expression could be like `$[?($.Id == 1)]` ?

Comment: Haven't checked but it might not be implemented, see [JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects #1256](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256).

Comment: @dbc Indeed, this could be the issue. For now I've added code in WireMock.Net to wrap an object in an JArray if needed.

Answer (score 4):

The path that you posted is not valid.  I think you meant `$..[?(@.Id == 1)]` (some characters were out of order).  My answer assumes this.

The JSON Path that you're using indicates that the item you're looking for should be in an array.

```
$                      start
 ..                    recursive search (1)
   [                   array item specification
    ?(                 item-based query
      @.Id == 1        where the item is an object with an "Id" with value == 1 at the root
               )       end item-based query
                ]      end array item specification

(1) the conditions following this could match a value no matter how deep in the hierarchy it exists
```

You want to just navigate the object directly.  Using `$.Id` will return `1`, which you can validate in your application.

**All of that said...**

It sounds to me like you want to *validate* that the `Id` property is `1` rather than to search an array for an object where the `Id` property is `1`.  To do this, you want JSON Schema, not JSON Path.

JSON Path is a query language for searching for values which meet certain conditions (e.g. an object where `Id == 1`.

[JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) is for validating that the JSON meet certain requirements (your data's in the right shape).  A JSON Schema to validate that your object has a value of `1` could be something like

```
{
  "properties": {
    "Id": {"const":1}
  }
}
```

Granted this isn't very useful because it'll only validate that the `Id` property is `1`, which ideally should only be true for one object.