# json path expression not working without array

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I am trying to implement what seems like a simple JSON path filter, but failing to get it working.  Wondering if others more experience with Json.NET's implementation of JSON path have ideas on next steps.

This scenario fails but I think should work?

```
var jsonText = @"{
    'event': {
        'data': {
            'intField': 1,
            'stringField': 'hello'
        }
    }
}";

JObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonText);
string jsonPath = "$.event.data[?(@.intField == 1)]";
IList<JToken> output = json.SelectTokens(jsonPath).ToList();

// this check fails
Assert.IsTrue(output.ToList().Count > 0);
```

If I massage the JSON payload by adding a dummy array around the 'data' object, then I can get the query working.  However, I would rather not massage the JSON payload.

```
var jsonText = @"{
    'event': {
        'data': [{
            'intField': 1,
            'stringField': 'hello'
        }]
    }
}";

JObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonText);
string jsonPath = "$.event.data[?(@.intField == 1)]";
IList<JToken> output = json.SelectTokens(jsonPath).ToList();

// now this works
Assert.IsTrue(output.ToList().Count > 0);
```

Comment: I believe this may just be a limitation of Json.NET.  See [Issue #1256: JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256).   It comes up here from time to time, e.g. [What's the correct JsonPath expression to search a JSON root object using Newtonsoft.Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49462187) and [How to filter a non-array in JsonPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43707780).  You might want to add a comment to the issue on github if this functionality would be useful to you.

Comment: You might check to see if the workaround from [Newtonsoft JSON.Net SelectToken Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39442443/3744182) works for you also.

Answer (score 6):

**The problem** is that Json.NET's implementation of the JsonPATH filter expression operator `[?()]` only works for filtering of objects inside collections (arrays) -- not objects inside other objects.  This limitation is reported in [Issue #1256: JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256), to which Newtonsoft replied,

> I'm not sure about this. Nothing in the JSONPath says that filters should apply to objects.
>
> **JamesNK** commented on Mar 24, 2017

This limitation comes up here from time to time, e.g. [What's the correct JsonPath expression to search a JSON root object using Newtonsoft.Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49462187) or [How to filter a non-array in JsonPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43707780).  You might want to add a comment to the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256) if you would find filtering for objects inside objects useful.

**A workaround** that sometimes does the job is to add the recursive descent operator `..` between the containing object property name and the filter expression operator, like so:

```
string jsonPath = "$.event.data..[?(@.intField == 1)]";
```

And, in your specific case, the modified query now works and selects one object.  Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gNeXWz).

Of course, this modified query will also match something like:

```
{
  "event": {
    "data": {
      "extra_added_level_of_nesting": {
        "intField": 1,
        "stringField": "hello"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ayVNoJ)) so the workaround may not be sufficient for your needs.

The workaround succeeds because, apparently, Json.NET considers the results returned by the recursive descent operator to be a collection, and thus can apply a filter expression operator to it.